# If tbody has more than one child, add show element1

Tags: jquery, css

I have problem with displaying content of one thiw if another div has more than one child element.

Here is the structure:

```
<div class="element1"></div>
<tbody>
  <tr></tr>
</tbody>

.element1 {
  display: none;
}
```

So, if tbody has only one child, then display .element1.

I tried so many things with css3, but I could not finish it.

Thank you

Comment: show us, what you have tried ?

Comment: That HTML is invalid. If it's inside a `table` element, you can't have a `div` there. If it's not, well, `tbody` isn't valid outside `table`.

Comment: There is table tag, I just wanted to explain more simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, if tbody has only one child, then display .element1.

I'm going to assume the second half of that is "...otherwise hide it."

You can do that like this:

```
$(".element1").toggle($("selector-for-the-table tbody").children().length === 1);
```

You need to trigger that code when the content of the table may have changed. You can do that using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on any modern browser. On slightly less-modern browsers, you can find a polyfill/shim that emulates enough of mutation observers using the old deprecated mutation events. On really old browsers, you'll have to poll.

Here's an example of a mutation observer watching the `tbody` for changes:

```
// Watch for changes
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
  // A change may have occurred
});
ob.observe($("selector-for-the-table tbody")[0], {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
// Function that does the update
function updateElement1() {
  $(".element1").toggle($("#the-table tbody").children().length === 1);
}

// Initial call
updateElement1();

// Watch for changes
var ob = new MutationObserver(updateElement1);
ob.observe($("#the-table tbody")[0], {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

// Change it once a second for 10 seconds
var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var tbody = $("#the-table tbody");
  if (tbody.children().length === 1) {
    // Add one
    tbody.append("<tr><td>Second row added " + new Date().toISOString() + "</td></tr>");
  } else {
    // Remove one
    tbody.children().last().remove();
  }
  if (++counter >= 10) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $("<p>").html("Done").appendTo(document.body);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="element1">I'm element 1</div>
<table id="the-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First row</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since the OP is asking for a way to do what he wants with CSS3 I would also add for clarity's sake that this "conditional" behaviour is not possible with pure CSS and Javascript code will need to be involved.

Comment: @Christina, op also added jquery tag in question so may be TJ is right.

Comment: @Christina, you are right, but the OP has put jquery in his tags indicating he is willing to accept answers with jquery

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you very much for quick and educational response. I have another question. Maybe I made a mistake because I only wrote "element1", because it actually looks like this:
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"></div> 

How can I select that element?

Comment: @MomciloPopov: Note that that's invalid HTML; `div` elements don't have those attributes. (They'll work, but it's invalid.) You might look at using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) instead. But you can select the `div` with the `itemprop` attribute with the value "offers" using an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): `$("div[itemprop=offers]")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('tbody tr').length > 1) {
    $('.element1').show();
}
```

But @T.J. Crowder is right in his comment.

I hope it helps.